# Using Firebase User UID to retrieve profile info

Tags: firebase-authentication

This is something of a follow-up question for [Best practice Fetch user's information from the Firebase User UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012765/best-practice-fetch-users-information-from-the-firebase-user-uid)

there is no admin SDK for my development language. I have found docs on the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-fetch-providers-for-email). You can get provider info for a particular email address, and you can fetch profile data for a currently-authenticated user by the auth token id, but I don't see a way to retrieve profile data based on the user uid. am i just missing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API only provides a public API that is a subset of the client SDKs (e.g. the web SDK). It is not an administrative API, and thus has no documented way to allow looking up a user's by a UID. You should think of it more as an API that allows you to create limited *clients* on platforms for which no full client SDK is available.

The [Fetch providers for email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-fetch-providers-for-email) section you linked is there for creating a client that can show the user a list of the provides they might have used to sign in before.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm guessing since you didn't mention a REST API for admin, there isn't one. Do you have any recommendations for server-side administration for languages not supported by the admin SDKs?

Comment: No sorry. I don't think that scenario is currently supported. The usual way to allow "User lookup by UID" is to store the information in a database, and allow querying there. In fact, that was the only way to do this for years, until the Admin SDK added an API for it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password